# Get Separate Textures from One Texture File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, textures

I am making a 2D tile based computer game in Javascript with jQuery, using the Canvas element. I have an image file that has multiple textures in one file, like the image below:

[image: Example of texture file]

For example, if I know that the width of each texture is `50 px`, then what is a way that I can just do `drawTexture(id, canvas)`, where `id` is the ID of the texture starting at 0 (the red in the picture is 0, the green is 1, the blue is 2, and the yellow is 3), and `canvas` is the 2D context from the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [slicing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Using_images#Slicing) functionality in `drawImage`.

```
<img id="source" src="myTileSheet.png" style="display:none"/>
```

```
var columns    = 2,   //  The amount of tile columns,
    tileWidth  = 50,  //  Tile width,
    tileHeight = 50,  //  Tile height.
    image      = document.getElementById('source'),
    canvas     = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
    ctx        = canvas.getContext('2d');

function drawTileAt(number, targetX, targetY){
    var sx = tileWidth * (Math.floor(number / columns)); // Get the X position.
    var sy = tileHeight * (number % columns);            // Y.

    // Where you want it on the canvas.
    ctx.drawImage(image,                  // Source image,
                  sx, sy,                 // Source X / Y to get the tile from,
                  tileWidth, tileHeight,  // Source Width / Height to crop out,
                  targetX, targetY,       // Destination X / Y to place the image,
                  tileWidth, tileHeight); // Destination W / H (can be used to scale a tile)
}
```

However, this assumes that `number` starts counting at 0. If you want your first tile to be numbered `1`, add this at the first line of the function:

```
number--;
```

So:

```
function drawTile(number){
    number--;
    var image = document.getElementById('source');
    // etc.
```

Comment: Awesome! I assume that all of the `50`'s in the code are the width/height? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'll make a edit to put those in a proper variable.

Comment: @mrfishie: I made it slightly more efficient, removing some redundant variables.
Please keep in mind that this can only be used when the tilesheet has leaded. You can use something like `image.addEventListener('load', init);`, where `init` is a function that starts your application.